# Download Acrobat reader on user choice in windows installer

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, acrobat

I want to download Adobe Acrobat Reader when user selects the option to download it in the Windows Installer Setup screen. I created a dialog for screen. Now, when user selects the checkbox, this download should start automatically. I have to write code for this in the installer class.

Answer (score 0):

In general, find the page on www.adobe.com where you can download the requested exe.
Than, in your code, use **WebRequest** to download the page, use [Html Agility](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (to simplify your task) to extract the link to the EXE to download, finally download the exe using:

```
try
{
     WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("[URL here]");
     WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
     Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
     //...
}
catch (Exception)
{
     MessageBox.Show("There was a problem downloading the file");
}
```

For example, for my OS and language, this is the [EXE link](http://ardownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/10.x/10.0.0/it_IT/AdbeRdr1000_it_IT.exe).

Comment: Never ever deep link any third party downloads without prior consent nor parse download pages to retrieve the direct URL. This might also exposes your users to possible security issues and/or broken links due to newer releases.

Comment: @Mario: you're right, I was just trying to answer this post... I didn't say it was the best thing to do...
Anyway, link the EXE directly is wrong because it can change in every moment; this is the reason I told to parse html page...
If the user download manually from a website, he visits that site and could be exposed to security issues...
Don't know...

Answer (score 0):

Either include the Acrobat Reader in your installation (its installer; I'm quite sure its license allows you to do so) and install it if required or don't bundle nor install it. Don't try to do a direct download from any third party site as this might violate their TOS. For the easiest solution, present the user with an option to open the default download page in case they're missing the requirement (in this case the Reader). I'd guess it's for your user manual or whatever to show? In that case I'd just include a note on the "setup finished" page or in the manual component's name (e.g. "User manual (requires a PDF reader)") to indicate that the document can't be opened without an additional program. Another alternative would be to use another format that can be understood without third party tools, e.g. a HTML, CHM or RTF file.

Comment: You need to apply to distribute Adobe Reader yourself - http://www.adobe.com/products/reader/distribution.html , usually approved within 24 hours.